# How to generate reports with user stories and sub-tasks in JIRA?

Tags: jira, agile

Imagine that I want to generate a report from JIRA for a Sprint, with user stories and sub-task. I am trying to generate a report from JIRA with the following format:

```
Key                   Summary                                    T
DEP-345               To integrate with the new web service     Story
DEP-346               To check SOA availability                 Sub-Task
DEP-347               To deploy WebService                      Sub-task
```

In the case above DEP-346 and DEP-347 are sub-tasks of DEP-345. The question is how can I generate this report. I tried the reporting in JIRA and also the Issues tab in JIRA. The closest that I could get was the following:

```
Key                   Summary                                Sub-Tasks             T
DEP-345               To integrate with the new web service  DEP-346, DEP-347   Story
```

Any idea how can I generate the report as described at the beginning? Is there a plugin in JIRA for it? I tried JQL but I was out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use JQL, what you need to select on is the custom field that Jira Agile plugin uses to attach Jiras to sprints. In the advanced query view, start typing "sprint" and the field name should come up. You can then set it to your sprint name to get the list of all the items in the sprint, including substasks.

Comment: thanks. I understand that I can use the JQL to get all the sub-tasks and stories for a sprint. However, my question was how can I get sub-tasks under its corresponding user story, not all user stories and then all sub-tasks.